# Why am I getting hung up on on this line of code which uses SumProduct?

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason, this section of code gets hung up on the "rng3.Value..." line. Please help.

```
Set rng4 = ActiveSheet.Columns("D").Find(strFind, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    rng4.Select
    Set lastCell2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, (4)).End(xlUp)
    lastCell2.Select
    Set rng5 = Range(rng4, lastCell2)
    rng5.Select
    Set rng5 = rng5.Offset(0, 0).Resize(rng5.Rows.Count - 1)
    rng5.Select
For i = 0 To 29
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").Select
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Columns("J").Find(strFind, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    rng1.Select
    Set lastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, (10)).End(xlUp)
    lastCell.Select
    Set rng2 = Range(rng1, lastCell)
    Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(4, i).Resize(rng2.Rows.Count - 5, rng2.Columns.Count)
    rng2.Select
    Set rng3 = Sheets("Results").Cells(18, (i + 7))
    'rng3.Value = Worksheets("Resource Plan").Evaluate("Sum(," & rng2.Address(0, 0) & ")")
    rng3.Value = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct("rng5", "rng3")
    Worksheets("Results").Select
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are variables, no quotes. Also adjust rng5 to drop the header. Then read it into an array. Currently you are using a range and the sumproduct needs an array.

```
Set rng5 = rng5.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng5.Rows.Count - 1)
For Each cell In rng5
    i = i + 1
    aRng5(i) = cell.Value
Next cell

rng3.Value = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(rng5, rng3)
```

The main issue seems to be that the arrays don't match in dimensions currently. You can't sumproduct a single cell against an array. You will probably end up looping through the rng5 if you want to multiple each cell by a value then add them together. In which case, you don't need to read it into an array, but can still use that for next format to loop through, multiply, then add the result to a variable. If the second range is supposed to match in size then you will need to use that same for next loop logic on that range also.

Comment: Still no go. The error now reads "Unable to get the SumProduct property of the WorksheetFunction class" Does this mean you can't use SumProduct in VBA?

Comment: If that doesn't do it, step through it and when you get to that line, check the data types of rng5 and rng3. You should be able to use this function just fine. That error comes up a lot when you are passing the wrong datatype.

Comment: both rng3 and rng5 are dimensioned as ranges

Comment: Actually I think I found it. You are selecting the range wrong. If you step through and each time you do a .select, look at your sheet, when you get to the line right before your for statement you have the string that you found selected down through the second to last cell in the column. I assume you want to strip the string at the top not the number at the bottom?

Comment: Oh, messages crossed ... sumproduct accepts arrays to multiply, not ranges. If you declare an array and populate it with numbers and then a second you can sumproduct with them just fine. Typically you would just declare the array and make it equal to the range but that give you a 2d array and sumproduct doesn't like 2d arrays it seems. I think you will have to populate it using for next with your set ranges. I'll see if I can get you a snippet that works for you.

Comment: Your arrays don't match either. rng3 is a single cell where rng5 is a larger range. if you select a large range manually in excel and try to do a sumproduct with a single cell, it won't work. I got it to work fine with 2d test arrays but they do need to have the same dimensions. so if you want to multiply each cell in rng5 by a single cell and then add them you will likely need to loop through your range and then multiply and add to a variable. Is that what you want to do ultimately?